# Moto E Won't detect Thumb drive

Tags: usb-on-the-go, motorola-moto-e

I have a Motorola Moto E, and according to USB Host Diagnostics, the stock OS and kernel claim OTG USB support, and the proper classes are present, but it won't detect a thumb drive connected via OTG cable.  I can't find a stock rom image for download, so, until I can, rooting is out of the question...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A Forums Manager on Motorola Forums said:

> Moto E will not support OTG.

See the full thread [here](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/d89af03a15).

Answer (score 0):

Some android devices do have hardware support for otg cables and the device will detect the usb device internally but won't mount. Try rooting and installing [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) and report back.

Comment: Like I said...I can't find a stock rom image.  I want to have a fallback in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Found an exact donor match (hopefully) for my firmware.  Just need to figure out how to root it without screwing it up...only used Poot and NRT before now.  Yeah, I'm a real noob.  I'll get back to y'all in a couple of days, assuming I haven't bricked it lol (well, half joking)